# Using Unity, how do you register type mappings for generics?

Tags: entity-framework, unity-container, repository-pattern, separation-of-concerns

I'm trying to implement a [repository solution for Entity Framework](http://blog.swink.com.au/index.php/c-sharp/generic-repository-for-entity-framework-4-3-dbcontext-with-code-first/) but I am having trouble registering the types that include generics using Unity.

Given:

```
    // IRepository interface
    public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }

    // Repository implementation
    public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable 
            where TEntity : class
            where TContext : DbContext
    {
        // omitted for brevity
    }

    // service layer constructor
    public MyServiceConstructor(IRepository<Account> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

I need to register the type mapping for IRepository to Repository. but I'm having trouble with the Unity syntax for this kind of mapping.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository<>, typeof(Repository<,>)>();
container.RegisterType<typeof(IRepository<>), Repository<,>>();
```

**EDIT**

Based, on @Steven response I have the following implementation now:

```
// UnityRepository implementation   
public class UnityRepository<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity, MyDbContextEntities>
        where TEntity : class
{
    public UnityRepository() : base(new MyDbContextEntities()) { }
}

// Unity bootstrapper
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(UnityRepository<>));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are trying to do the following:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<,>));
```

This would normally work, but won't do the trick in this case, since there is `IRepository<TEntity>` has one generic argument and `Repository<TEntity, TContext>` has two, and Unity (obviously) can't guess what type it should fill in for `TContext`.

What you need is this:

```
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(Repository<, MyDbContextEntities>));
```

In other words, you'd want to supply the `Repository<TEntity, TContext>` as a partial open generic type (with one parameter filled in). Unfortunately, the C# compiler does not support this.

But even if the C# did support this, Unity doesn't support partial open generic types. In fact most IoC libraries eworks don't support this. And for that [one library](https://simpleinjector.org) that does support it, you would still have to do the following (nasty thing) to create the partial open generic type:

```
Type myDbContextEntitiesRepositoryType =
    typeof(Repository<,>).MakeGenericType(
        typeof(Repository<,>).GetGenericParameters().First(),
        typeof(MyDbContextEntities));
```

There's a easy <strike>trick</strike> work around to get this to work though: define a derived class with one generic type:

```
// Special implementation inside your Composition Root
public class UnityRepository<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity, MyDbContextEntities>
        where TEntity : class
{
    public UnityRepository([dependencies]) : base([dependencies]) { }
}
```

Now we can easily register this open generic type:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(UnityRepository<>));
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my edit above.  Do you recommend placing the `UnityRepository` implementation in the composition root/unity bootstrapper, or in a separate class file within the Repository layer? I currently have it in the latter.  And when you say public `UnityRepository([dependencies]) : base([dependencies]) { }`, I assume you mean `public UnityRepository(TEntity entity) : base(new MyDbContextEntities()) { }`.  I currently have it setup as `public UnityRepository(TEntity entity) : base(new MyDbContextEntities()) { }` and it's working fine.

Comment: Since this class is tiny and just an implementation detail of the Composition Root, I usually create them as private nested classes inside the bootstrapper class.

Comment: @MarkErasmus: Since the `UnityRepository` is just a helper class, you typically want it to have the same constructor arguments as the original class. This way you can still let the container do the wiring for you. So I would expect the `UnityRepository` to accept a `MyDbContextEntities`, or in your case probably no arguments at all. Passing in a `TEntity` is odd, since you shouldn't use your container to create entities at all.

Comment: Have a solution for design time configuration? XML?

Comment: @IssaFram: Yes, the solution is simple: don't configure your container through XML. No seriously: don't do it.