# How can I dynamically register generic classes with a name with Unity?

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have an assembly with a lot of classes (300+) with a BaseClass and I want register a generic class with a interface.

With unity you have to register by {**Name**} if you want to resolve an array of objects of the interface.
I want an array of objects in the **MainViewModel** automatically.

Is there a way to automate this with reflection?
Any suggestions?

Example (pseudo):

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public void doFoo();
}

public ClassNumber001 : BaseClass
{
}
public ClassNumber002 : BaseClass
{
}

public interface ISuperman
{
}

public class Superman : ISuperman where T : BaseClass
{
}

public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<ISuperman> lotsofSuperman)
{
}
```

Working example by hand:

```
container.RegisterType<ISuperman, Superman <ClassNumber001>>("ClassNumber001");
container.RegisterType<ISuperman, Superman <ClassNumber002>>("ClassNumber002");
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<ISuperman>, ISuperman[]>();
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to do it by reflection? Which Unity version are you using, above 3.x ?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory, I mentioned reflection because I used that before. (to find al the 300 classes)
I use Unity 3.5.1404.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that comes to my mind that might work for you...

You can register the type as follows, and should work for the [open generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880526/using-unity-how-do-you-register-type-mappings-for-generics?answertab=active#tab-top).

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ISuperman<>), typeof(Superman<>), ... );
```

[Registering generic parameters and types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to use reflection to **easily** create all of the mappings that you want.  Since you are using Unity 3 you can take advantage of [Registration by Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec23) to provide help (with the heavier lifting) in registering the classes.

I've taken your pseudo code and translated it into real code:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void DoFoo();
}

public class ClassNumber001 : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("001 Foo");
    }
}

public class ClassNumber002 : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("002 Foo");
    }
}

public interface ISuperman
{
    void Do();
}

public class Superman<T> : ISuperman where T : BaseClass
{
    private T baseClass;

    public Superman(T baseClass)
    {
        this.baseClass = baseClass;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        this.baseClass.DoFoo();
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<ISuperman> lotsofSuperman)
    {
        foreach(ISuperman superman in lotsofSuperman)
        {
            superman.Do();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use registration by convention to register all the generics:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where(t => typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Select(t => typeof(Superman<>).MakeGenericType(t)),
    t => new Type[] { typeof(ISuperman) },
    t => t.GetGenericArguments().First().Name,
    WithLifetime.Transient);

container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<ISuperman>, ISuperman[]>();

container.Resolve<MainViewModel>();
```

In the above code we get all classes that inherit from `BaseClass` and then construct a type `Superman<>` and map that to `ISuperman` using the name of the `BaseClass`.  The RegisterTypes call will be equivalent to calling RegisterType for every BaseClass:

```
container.RegisterType<ISuperman, Superman<ClassNumber001>("ClassNumber001");
container.RegisterType<ISuperman, Superman<ClassNumber002>("ClassNumber002");
```

Then when `MainViewModel` is resolved it iterates over all `ISuperman` instances and calls a method which prints out:

> 001 Foo
>   002 Foo

showing that we injected 2 `ISuperman` instances: `Superman<ClassNumber001>` and `Superman<ClassNumber002>`.

If you need specific registrations for the BaseClasses (e.g. non-default lifetime manager) then you can use registration by convention to register those too).

Answer (score 0):

There are some of the ways this can be done. One is by using XML where the type is defined lets say MyClass and IMyClass and during runtime it resolves based on the assemblies available. But a better approach in my opinion would be to create a project to which you can delegate the responsibility of loading up the dependencies.

Lets say you create a class like so:

```
     public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        #ctor
        // initialie the container through the constructor

        public void DoWork<Interface, Class>() where Class: Interface
        {
            _container.RegisterType<Interface, Class>(
             //TODO: You can setup the container lifecycle which can be transient
             // or singleton or custom based on your project requirement  
             )
        }
    }
```

Now whoever needs to register itself can call this interface IMyClass to get itself registered in the container and dependency can be injected to whichever class needs to perform that task.