# Dependency Injection to launch view as Dialog in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I need some advice for how I should handle dependency injection in my ViewModel. My viewModel `MenuViewModel` has an `ICommand` method which will run when the user clicks on the button in the view. This method is going to open a new window. The method is shown under here.

```
public void bookingCommand_DoWork(object obj)
{
    BookingView bookingView = new BookingView();
    BookingViewModel model = new BookingViewModel();
    bookingView.DataContext = model;

    bookingView.ShowDialog();
}
```

It creates an instance of `BookingView` and `BookingViewModel`. I'm trying to use dependency injection instead of creating the instance like this.

**MenuViewModel**

```
public class MenuViewModel : IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    //commands
    public ICommand bookingCommand { get; set; }

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        bookingCommand = new RelayCommand(bookingCommand_DoWork, () => true);
    }

    public void bookingCommand_DoWork(object obj)
    {
        BookingView bookingView = new BookingView();
        BookingViewModel model = new BookingViewModel();
        bookingView.DataContext = model;

        bookingView.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

The `IViewMainWindowViewModel` is an empty interface which makes the contract between my MainWindow and MenuViewModel.

**My unity startup method I'm using**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
        container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MenuViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingView>();

        container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
        //Do the same actions for  all views and their viewmodels
    }
```

Well, my `MenuViewModel` depends on the `BookingView` & `BookingViewModel`.

Should I inject that into the constructor or?

Hope someone can give some advice.

**Update (Currently working for me)**

What I have done so far:

**1. App Class**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IUnityContainer _container;

    public IUnityContainer UnityContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null)
            {
                _container = new UnityContainer();

            }
            return _container;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MenuViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingView>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingViewModel>();

        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IDialogService<>), typeof(DialogService<>));

        _container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
    }

}
```

**2. Create IDialogService and import container from App class.**

```
public interface IDialogService<T>
{
    void Show();
    void ShowDialog();
}

public class DialogService<T> : IDialogService<T> where T : Window
{

    public void Show()
    {
        var container = ((App)Application.Current).UnityContainer;
        container.Resolve<T>().Show();
    }

    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        var container = ((App)Application.Current).UnityContainer;
        container.Resolve<T>().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Here I now got an *error* with the Show and ShowDialog method.

*"T" does not contain a definition of "Show" / "ShowDialog" and no extension method "Show" / "ShowDialog" accepting a first argument of type T.*

**3. Inject the service in the MenuViewModel**

```
public class MenuViewModel : IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    //commands
    public ICommand bookingCommand { get; set; }

    //entities
    private IDialogService<BookingView> _dialogService;


    public MenuViewModel(IDialogService<BookingView> dialogService)
    {
        // Injecting
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        bookingCommand = new RelayCommand(bookingCommand_DoWork, () => true);
    }

    public void bookingCommand_DoWork(object obj)
    {
        _dialogService.ShowDialog();

    }
}
```

Comment: In MVC context, commands in model looks strange.

Comment: What do you mean? This is wpf?

Comment: you need to properly register service. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880526/using-unity-how-do-you-register-type-mappings-for-generics

Comment: what is the type of your BookingView?

Comment: The BookingView implements a empty interface which BookingViewModel also does. Have added the BookingView class.

Comment: you will have to add contraint to you service class `where T : Window`. Updated the answer too

Comment: Also in your App class instead of creating new container for registering type, use UnityContainer property instead of container variable in onstartup

Comment: Yes I have it now :D , works! Thank you so much for this, appreciate a lot

Comment: great!! hope it will help for future development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are scenarios where we have to launch views as Model or ModeLess dialogs. To keep things in boundary of MVVM, I would rather create a separate service for launching views as dialog so that it can be used in a generic way across the application. And will inject this service to the ViewModel via Constructor which wants to launch any dialog.

```
public interface IDialogService<T>
{
    void Show();
    void ShowDialog();
}

public class DialogService<T> : IDialogService<T> where T : Window
{
    public void Show()
    {
        container.Resolve<T>().Show();
    }

    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        container.Resolve<T>().ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Now I will inject this service to the respective viewmodel.

```
public class MenuViewModel : IViewMainWindowViewModel
{
    //commands
    public ICommand bookingCommand { get; set; }

    private IDialogService<BookingView> _dialogService;
    public MenuViewModel(IDialogService<BookingView > dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService
        bookingCommand = new RelayCommand(bookingCommand_DoWork, () => true);
    }

    public void bookingCommand_DoWork(object obj)
    {
        //Since you want to launch this view as dialog you can set its datacontext in its own constructor.

        _dialogService.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

In App.xaml.cs you can define property like below. Then you can use property UnityContainer and then in service you can get container like `var container = ((App) Application.Current).UnityContainer;`

```
    public IUnityContainer _container;
    public IUnityContainer UnityContainer
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null)
            {
              _container = new UnityContainer();

            }
            return _container;
        }
    }
```

Doing this will help keeping your VM testable as you can inject the mock of the service through your tests too.

Comment: The container field, where do you get that?

Comment: Thats just the demo code I showed. You can expose the UnityContainer from the application and use it whereever you like.

Comment: I'm not quite following what you mean.. take a look at my Update.

Comment: I think I have registered the types correctly now.

Now its only the container does not exist in the DialogService.. any hints?

Comment: you can create a public property for container in App class and then use it throughout the application

Comment: Could you maybe show me? I guess I need the container instanse I created in the OnStartup method in the App class. This is just a over my level of programming, so I'm not following.

Comment: Updated with that I got.. not sure what I have done wrong so far.

Comment: Isn't this service locator, not dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

When you write the following rows of code:

```
BookingView bookingView = new BookingView();
BookingViewModel model = new BookingViewModel();
bookingView.DataContext = model;
bookingView.ShowDialog();
```

You are violating MVVM rule as `viewmodel` should know **nothing** `Views`. I suggest you to use `DataTemplates`.

It is appropriate to use `DataTemplates` if you want to dynamically switch `Views` depending on the `ViewModel`:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelA}">
         <localControls:ViewAUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelB}">
         <localControls:ViewBUserControl/>
      </DataTemplate>
   <Window.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
</Window>
```

If `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelA`, then `ViewA` will be displayed and `Window.DataContext` is an instance of `ViewModelB`, then `ViewB` will be displayed.

The best example I've ever seen and read it is made by Rachel Lim. [See the example.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will take a look at this.