# How to register all validators generically

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, fluentvalidation

I have a problem with dependency injection using open generic types.

To register a validator now, I must write:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<User>, UserValidator>();
```

I need something like this:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(Validator<>));
```

where `UserValidator` class is

```
 public class UserValidator : Validator<User>
 {
        public UserValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(user => user.Email).EmailAddress();
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity Container *does* support registration of open generics ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880526/using-unity-how-do-you-register-type-mappings-for-generics)'s an example of someone doing that), but you are wanting mappings to concrete, non-generic classes. The built in functionality will resolve an open generic interface to a closed generic class.

Your attempted registration

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(Validator<>));
```

will resolve to a `Validator<User>`, which you clearly don't want. There's no way using the built in functionality to tell it "I really want you to resolve to the non-generic subclass of `Validator<User>`".

What I suggest instead is that you create an extension method on `IUnityContainer` that will reflect over the assembly looking for non-generic validators, and register those individually.